# Запуск нескольких экземпляров приложения под разными пользователями Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Возможно ли запустить несколько интерфейсов одного и того же приложения под разными пользователями системы ubuntu? Если да, то как? Если возможно на примере skype или Steam 3 экземпляра

P.s. Нужно больше одного экземпляра (интерфейса) на экране какого либо приложения (прим skype, steam)

Comment: why not ???????

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, как?

Comment: ну заходим в юзера 1 запускаем, заходим в юзера 2 запускаем ;)

Comment: не знаю как сейчас, а раньше со скайпом было просто - создаем каталог, который подсовываем как домашний и поехали. А вообще то su/sudo решает все. А вот захотят ли они - это другое дело

Comment: Или вы так хотите: `sudo -u user1 ./path/to/app & sudo -u user2 ./path/to/app &` ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, Check your DISPLAY environment variable and make sure that you have enabled X.  If you are running remotely, make sure that you have a remote connection which will allow an X connection.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, мне не просто запустить, а получить 2-3 интерфейса одного приложения

Comment: xinit.............

Comment: Xyphir, Xnest и в них можно внутри запустить. А может просто передать DISPLAY прям командной строке.

Comment: @KoVadim, можно пожалуйста поподробней как дисплей передать

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, можно пожалуйста хоть один пример с использованием xinit? Как запустить мне в нем приложение чтобы не было этой ошибки

Comment: Ну это на самом деле не то, просто вспомнил. Вот пример, если находишься например на первой консоле (т.е. в тесктовом моде), то графическую прогу можно запустить так: `xinit path/to/app -- :9`

Comment: `DISPLAY=:1 xterm`, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xephyr

Comment: @KoVadim, sudo -u user1 DISPLAY=:0 ./path/to/app Выдаёт ту же ошибку

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEygm.gif  ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, спасибо большое за доходчивость! Но смогу ли я так запустить 4 приложения (одно и то же) от разных пользователей